# Location of httpd.conf file on my webserver

Tags: apache

Hey guys i have setup a home server on my pc and i can  see and edit and make changes to my httpd.conf file on my home server of my computer

But when i move to my web server i cant see the location of my httpd.conf file..Is it on the www directory of the website ??..or on any other locationss ??

i have checked everywhere on the internet and i didnt found any proper answer for the location of httpd.conf file.Hope you guys can help me out to solve the problem.

Any help would be appreciated ..

Comment: am on windows ...i have found .htaacess file on my web directory ..in public-html section but i didnt find httpd.conf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will depend on what OS you are using.
I am using windows and xampp for web development.

> The location of my httdp.conf is

```
C:\xampp\apache\conf
```

Comment: i know that ..but my question is how can i find the location of httpd.conf file on my cpanel ..is it found on the www directory ..

Comment: so if i use ssh and connect my webserver  and type locate httpd.conf ..will i get the location of httpd.conf file in my server directory ??

Comment: when i navigate through file manager and looked for apache folder i didnt even found it ....can you tell me why i cant see my httpd.conf file directly ..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux you can use the locate command:

```
locate httpd.conf
```

Comment: am on windows ...i have found .htaacess file on my web directory ..in public-html section but i didnt find httpd.conf file

Comment: so if i use ssh and connect my webserver and type locate httpd.conf ..will i get the location of httpd.conf file in my server directory ??